# React Native bundling: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: operator (*)

Tags: ios, react-native, uglifyjs, react-native-ios

When I run attempt to bundle my app with:

```
react-native bundle --platform ios --dev false \
    --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output iOS/main.jsbundle
```

I get the following error, with no other details:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token: operator (*)
```

For what it's worth, this works (with `--dev true`):

```
react-native bundle --platform ios --dev true \
    --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output iOS/main.jsbundle
```

My best guess is that the issue is somewhere in an UglifyJS step, perhaps related to:

https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2/issues/1199

Any tips? Suggestions for where to dig deeper are welcome! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We found the line number with:

```
./node_modules/.bin/esvalidate --formatter=sublime.js ios/main.jsbundle
```

The issue was the use of the `**` ES6 operator. Reverted to `Math.pow()`.

Comment: In my case **main.jsbundle** failed to build due to me replacing **Math.pow** with the ** operator as ESLint prompted.  The bundle error was **Unexpected token: operator (*)**.
Is there a way to find the line number if there is no **main.jsbundle** to run **esvalidate** on?  In my case, I suspected the problem and regex found it.  Is there a **verbose** option for **react-native bundle** ?